# How do I use induction to prove this set relation?

Tags: induction, relations

We are given a binary relation $R \subseteq X \times X$ and $R^+ \subseteq X \times X$, where $R \subseteq R^+$.

Given the axiom $$\frac{}{(x,x) \in R^+} ,\ (x \in X)$$ 
and the rule: $$\frac{(x,y) \in R^+}{(x,z) \in R^+},\ (x\in X \land (y,z) \in R)$$

We want to use rule induction to prove that $R^+$ is a subset of the following set S:

$$S = \{(y,z) \in X \times X : \forall x\in X. (x,y) \in R^+ \implies (x,z) \in R^+\}$$

and thus show that $R^+$ is transitive.

My thoughts:

1. To show  that $R^+$ is a subset of $S$, I got to show that for any element of $R^+$ implies that element is also in $S$.
2. Looking at how $S$ requires $(y,z)$, I am thinking of showing the transitive relation $(y,x) \in R^+ \land (x,z)\in R^+ \implies (y,z) \in R^+$.
3. But the problem is I cannot be sure $(y,x) \in R^+$ since I only know it's $(x,y) \in R^+$. Also, even if I can prove the statement in point 2, I cannot show it means $(y,z) \in S$.

How should I proceed further?

Comment: I do not follow the notation (though I assume it is standard), what do the axiom and the rule say, informally? (Edit. The axiom appears to say that the diagonal is a subset of $R^+$, and I am trying to make sense of the rule now.)

Comment: Which diagonal do you refer to?

Comment: the diagonal in this context usually refers to the "diagonal" of the "square" $X\times X$, namely the set $\Delta=\{(x,x):x\in X\}$. Please also see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Diagonal_Relation and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1944400

Comment: Maybe you have read this in a book on formal languages and automata. But the question does not really have anything to do with these topics, but rather with relations and sets. I edit the tags accordingly.

Comment: Let R be empty and R+ any reflexive, non transitive relation and you have a counterexample without that  big S monster.  Rule notation is terrible:  just use words.